# mod_rewrite and {QUERY_STRING}

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

Changed my url from

```
http://www.website.com/b.php?n=45&t=example
```

to this

```
http://www.website.com/45/example
```

by using this mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/(.*) /b.php?n=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA]
```

How do I get my query strings to still work because I want to use $_GET

```
echo '<img src="gifs/' . $_GET["t"] . '/' . $_GET["n"] . '.gif">';
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what your problem is? In what way does `$_GET` not contain what you want? Is it simply that `n=$1&b=$2` should be `n=$1&t=$2`?

Comment: If you rewrote the URL correctly, you should be able to access $_GET['n'] and $_GET['t'] just the same as always. Have you tried accessing those vars?

Comment: Yes, [QSA] should allow you to get the query string still? In this case you can rebuild the GET array based on the $_server variables.

Comment: @mario Hey I thought this was a better question from what I learnt last time! Sorry buddy

Comment: @tomhallam I have added my $_GET code to get the image

Comment: @user1616846 What output does the above `echo` statement produce? A more useful diagnostic output might be the result of `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: @DaveRandom Sorry dave. Added my echo statement above! cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following .htaccess code for sending the full url to the b.php file and there you can split the url using the **explode** function and can get the query strings separately

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/* b.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: So I just add this onto my .htaccess and then what do I do. I am not sure what you mean by explode function? Cheers buddy